# cucumber failed to load 'txt' programming language

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to run a basic cucumber feature in text file: calculator/features/adding.feature.txt:

```
Feature: Adding

Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given the input "2+2"
    When the calculator is run
    Then the output should be "4"
```

When in the ../calculator/ directory and run `cucumber`, I get the output:
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s

When I run `cucumber-v`, I get the output:

> Failed to load 'txt' programming language for file features/adding.feature.txt: cannot load such file -- cucumber/txt_support/txt_language
>     * features/adding.feature.txt [NOT SUPPORTED]

I have installed the latest version of ruby for 64bit, the latest devkit and `gem install cucumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Gherkin conventions](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin), feature files must have extension `.feature` (`.txt` is not allowed). Try to remove `.txt` extension of your feature file: `adding.feature`

Comment: The name is adding.feature, but it is a text file.

Comment: The extension can't be `.txt`. Name has to be adding, extension `.feature`:adding.feature, Could you try to change it?